# Create Generic List from a subclass

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, reflection

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Public Class Class1

    Dim l As List(Of A)

    Public Sub New()
        l = New List(Of B)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class A
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
End Class<p>
```

I've run into this problem.
I have a list declared of a Generic Type 'A'
I want to define the list as a Generic Type 'B', which is a subclass of 'A'.

Why can't this be done, and how can the same effect be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of variance, which C# doesn't support for generics. See [Rick Byer's post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you could cast a list of As as a list of Bs, then what would happen if you added an A?

Comment: If the class A was used as the Generic type then it should act as an interface for any subclasses added.
You should be able to use any methods / variables in A and B, and B if you explicitly cast it.

Comment: Though obviously not, I'll think on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 4.0 (as announced yesterday) we are [half way there](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/10/28/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).